# DIDISOFT PGP file encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, pgp

anybody knows how to change `@"C:\Test\public_key.asc"` from manually input to using openfiledialog?

I tried to do that, there is this red zizag line under the code and when i put my mouse over, it says that it cannot convert System.IO.FileInfo to System.IO.Stream.

```
using System.IO;
using DidiSoft.Pgp;

class EncryptDemo {
 public void Demo() {
     // create an instance of the library
     PGPLib pgp = new PGPLib();

     // specify should the output be ASCII or binary
     bool asciiArmor = false;
     // should additional integrity information be added
     // set to false for compatibility with older versions of PGP such as 6.5.8.
     bool withIntegrityCheck = false;

     pgp.EncryptFile(@"C:\Test\INPUT.txt",
                     @"C:\Test\public_key.asc",
                     @"C:\Test\OUTPUT.pgp",
                     asciiArmor,
                     withIntegrityCheck);
 }
}
```

The below does not help us well because it does not open a dialog box for me to choose my file.

```
    bool asciiArmor = false;
    bool withIntegrityCheck = false;
    using (var publickey = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        pgp.EncryptFile(@attachmentTextBox.Text, publickey, @"C:\OUTPUT.pgp", asciiArmor, withIntegrityCheck);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
bool asciiArmor = false;
bool withIntegrityCheck = false;
pgp.EncryptFile(@attachmentTextBox.Text, openFileDialog1.FileName, @"C:\OUTPUT.pgp", asciiArmor, withIntegrityCheck);
```